# What does a probability being i.i.d means?

Tags: probability, terminology

I know that a sequence of random variables is i.i.d means that they have the same mutually independent probability distribution.

I was reading in a paper where the authors said that "*the probability of an event **A** is assumed i.i.d*".

What does it mean that a probability is i.i.d? Does this make any sense?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Here is the [article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5738217&tag=1).

And here is a snapshot (in case someone cannot have access).
[image]

Comment: i.i.d. is short for "identical and independently distributed". It means that all the random variables in your sequence have the same probability distribution and are independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense to speak of a single event, or the probability of a single event, as being iid.  However, if you post more context (or a reference to the paper itself), it may become more clear what the authors meant.

Comment: What does this mean? "where the probability of a channel being occupied by any primary user in any slot is assumed to be i.i.d" (line 4 in the figure above).

Answer (score 1):

i.i.d. stands for independent, identically distributed. It means the random variables are independent and have the same distributions. However, it does not make sense to refer to an event as i.i.d.

Answer (score 1):

a probability being i.i.d (independent and identically distributed) can basically be expressed in two steps:

**1)** when the outcomes of a random variable does not affect each other "independent".

**2)** when the outcomes share the same distribution with the same parameters. For example, assume the distribution to be N(0,1/2), that is normal with mean=0 and variance=1.

I will give you a concrete example of (i.i.d.), think of tossing a coin 'n' number of times. Now, in this case, our random variable is "coin", the probability of having head is =1/2 and the probability of having no head is = 1/2. Therefore, they are **"identically distributed"**! Also, the outcomes are **"independent"**, they do not affect each other! Therefore, this probability is (i.i.d.)!

I hope this makes it clear and easy!